# open a url feed in codeigniter

Tags: security, url, codeigniter, feed

What's the best way to open a URL feed in codeigniter? I'm assuming I can't put the URL in a file upload input, so should I use a normal text input and then validate that the URL is not malicious? If so, what validation tests should I perform on the user inputted string? Would checking the file extension be enough or can this easily be manipulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a `<input type="text" />` to let users submit URLs
2. Check that it is a valid URL using regular expressions (and ignore the extension)

   - e.g. `preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);`
3. Consider validating the feed with a feed validator (note that many legit feeds may not be "valid")

   - e.g. http://feedvalidator.org/about.html#where
   - e.g. http://www.rss-specifications.com/feed-validators.htm
4. Try accessing and parsing it

   - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/RSSParser/
   - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/RSSParser-PhilMod/
   - http://www.haughin.com/code/simplepie/

Comment: That's great - thanks. One more thing though... I think my using the word "feed" was misleading because it's actually a google cal ics file that I'm wanting to access, not an rss feed. Once I've checked the URL string against a regex, are there any other ways to validate the file before I open it?

Comment: There's not much you can do without accessing the URL. You could check the MIME type for "text/calendar", but I wouldn't consider that a best practice (or very reliable). I would also look into ICS/iCal validators / parsers (ical4j); perhaps you could port something to PHP, or call it from PHP.